# Creating array out of list

Tags: python

My code is like this:

```
for register in registerlist1:

    Parentlist1.append(register._getParent().getname())
    Classlist1.append(register.getaddress())
    Classlist1.append(register.getdirection())

    ClassList1.append(Parentlist1)
    ClassList1.append(Classlist1)
    print ClassList1

    Parentlist1=[]
    Classlist1=[]
    ClassList1=[]
```

Output:

```
[['B'], [1000, 'IN']]
[['C'], [1001, 'OUT']]
```

I want to store my each output in array like this:

```
ClassList1[0] =[['B'], [1000, 'IN']]
ClassList1[1] =[['C'], [1001, 'OUT']]
```

Note: `registerlist1` contains the instance which gives me address and direction.

Can someone help me here??

Comment: how about ClassList.append(ClassList1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify your code and build your lists directly, and build an outer list by appending:

```
class_list  = []
for register in registerlist1:
    class_list.append([
        [register._getParent().getname()],
        [register.getaddress()), register.getdirection()
    ])

print class_list
```

The above code builds the nested lists in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[register._getParent().getname()], [register.getaddress(), register.getdirection()]]for register in registerlist1]
```